# Polygon Won't Show Up In The Screen

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, drawing

I am trying to draw a 6 sided [obelisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelisk) using opengl.

Below is the code I use to model the bottom surface of the obelisk:

```
void drawObelisk() {
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for ( x=0.0; x<2.0*pi/3; x=x+inc )
    {   
        glVertex3f(0.3*cos(x),0.3*sin(x),0.0);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

This code is used to render the model:

```
void myDisplay(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    drawObelisk();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}

void SetupRC(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glOrtho(-6.0,6.0,-6.0,6.0,-6.0,6.0);
}

void main(void)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,15);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    SetupRC();
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

For certain reasons the polygon surface that I drew didn't show up on the screen once the model is rendered.

Comment: This snippet of code is nontelling without having the context. Ideally we'd see your whole rendering function and OpenGL context setup.

Comment: the respective code has been added. thank you...

Comment: supplied code is not enough. what is drawArrow(), inc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

void drawObelisk() 
{
    double pi = 3.14159;
    double inc = (2*pi) / 6;

    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for( double theta = 0.0; theta < 2*pi; theta += inc )
    {   
        double scale = 2.0;
        double x = scale * cos( theta );
        double y = scale * sin( theta );
        glVertex3d(x,y,0.0);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-6.0,6.0,-6.0,6.0,-6.0,6.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    drawObelisk();
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
}

void main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,15);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

[image: output]

Things that were wonky:

- Missing [`glutInit()`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html) call.
- `glClear()`ing the depth buffer without requesting one via `GLUT_DEPTH`.
- [Not switching to `GL_MODELVIEW` after setting your projection matrix.](http://sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html)
- Original `drawObelisk()` `for`-loop only generated two vertices.  `GL_POLYGON` needs a minimum of three.